# Launch Google Chrome from the command line with specific window coordinates

Tags: bash, google-chrome

I'm trying to find a shell command that will open Google Chrome with specific x and y coordinates (so that I can set the position of the window when it opens.) Is it possible to do this using command line-arguments?

I need to modify the following command in order to achieve this:

`google-chrome http://www.google.com/`

Comment: The problem is not solved on ubuntu 18.04 now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ says --window-position=x,y is what you're looking for.

Updating this years later to include a small shell script I wrote years ago (but after answering this question) that provides an example of how to start chrome with custom window sizes/position and has the ability to create 'fake' user data directories by name.

It may or may not still work, and has some dangerous options set, but you get the idea.. Do not use this verbatim, some of the flags may have been renamed or been removed entirely.. (like the socks proxy commands did)

```
#!/bin/bash -x

FAKEUSER="${1:-fake-chrome-user}"
CHROMEROOT=$HOME/.chromeroot/

mkdir -p ${CHROMEROOT}

export PROFILE="${CHROMEROOT}/${FAKEUSER}-chromium-profile"
export DISK_CACHEDIR="${CHROMEROOT}/${FAKEUSER}-chromium-profile-cache"
export DISK_CACHESIZE=4096
export MEDIA_CACHESIZE=4096

PARANOID_OPTIONS="\
        --no-displaying-insecure-content \
        --no-referrers \
        --disable-zero-suggest \
        --disable-sync  \
        --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0004,0x0005,0xc011,0xc007 \
        --enable-sandbox-logging >/dev/null 2>&1
        "


/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome \
        --remember-cert-error-decisions \
        --ignore-certificate-errors \
        --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests \
        --allow-running-insecure-content \
        --window-position=2400,400 \
        --window-size=1500,1000 \
        --no-pings \
        --user-data-dir=${PROFILE} \
        --disk-cache-dir=${DISK_CACHEDIR} \
        --disk-cache-size=${DISK_CACHESIZE} \
        --media-cache-size=${MEDIA_CACHESIZE} \
        2>&1


#--proxy-server="socks4://localhost:30604" \
#--host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost" \
```

Comment: Can it also be done for Firefox and IE? i posted a question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626884/chrome-app-equivalent-in-firefox-ie

Comment: Saddly this doesn't always work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592020/google-chrome-new-window-switch-ignores-window-position-and-window-size#comment30263659_14592020

Comment: It does work, @GregBray, but you need to set the `--user-data-dir` flag, too.

Answer (score 51):

When you're using Google's Chrome, there is a shorter way:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" 
     --profile-directory="Default"
     --app="data:text/html,<html><body><script>window.moveTo(580,240);window.resizeTo(800,600);window.location='http://www.test.de';</script></body></html>"
```

Pro:

- Automatically opens the window
- Avoids the popup-blocker
- Opens multiple windows on different monitors (multi monitor setup, requires two or more Chrome profiles)

Con:

- Only seems to work in "app" Mode
- Not tested with other browsers

Comment: Another "pro" -- it works with ordinary browser profiles, as of Chrome 51; the other answer apparently does not.

Comment: Great, thank you a lot! This is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Would like to have an address bar. How did this window even become a popup?

Comment: Does this work on osx?

Comment: @avgJoe, yes it works on all operating systems including OSX. an example of how to call Chrome on OSX you see in the other answer.

Comment: This will not work if there is another window already opened using the same profile!  There will be only a screen flicker but no window is opened.

Answer (score 27):

To build on @synthesizerpatel's answer, `--window-position` won't work on it's own.

You'll need to launch it as it's own new instance using `--user-data-dir` or `--chrome-frame` like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --user-data-dir=XXXXXXXXXX --window-size=800,600 --window-position=580,240 --app="http://www.google.com/"
or
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --chrome-frame --window-size=800,600 --window-position=580,240 --app="http://www.google.com/"
```

Unfortunately for me, having it as a new instance means it doesn't carry over the session/cookie/etc info from other instances, so I've had to open it normally (with only the `--app` parameter), then have javascript in the page I open do:

```
window.moveTo(580,240);
window.resizeTo(800,600);
```

I guess if you were opening a webpage owned by someone else, you could open your own webpage that has the above js, and then navigates to their webpage.

Comment: the option --chrome-frame didn't work for me, but with `--user-data-dir` i got it working. thanks

Comment: Looks like it has been deprecated

Comment: Can it also be done for Firefox and IE? i posted a question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626884/chrome-app-equivalent-in-firefox-ie

Comment: Works for me on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian and lightdm.

Comment: The `--user-data-dir` option works for me (on MacOS), but the command will now block. To work around this, the command has to be suffixed by an `&` on the command line, or the user has to press Ctrl+C after they're done (closing the window does not unblock the process)

Answer (score 4):

I've used this:

```
google-chrome "data:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1,<html>
    <head></head><body><script language=\"javascript\">
        window.open('http://perso.f-hauri.ch/~felix/svg/dustin_w_Clock_autonom.svg',
             'clock','toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,'
             +'resizable=1,width=600,height=600,top=100,left=120');</script>"
```

but *google-chrome* block *popup windows*, so this:

```
google-chrome "data:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1,<html><head></head><body>
    <button onclick=\"javascript:window.open(
        'http://perso.f-hauri.ch/~felix/svg/dustin_w_Clock_autonom.svg',
        'clock','toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1,'
        +'resizable=1,width=600,height=600,top=100,left=120');\"> clock </button>"
```

give a nice way to do this.

**Nota:** This work as well with firefox too.

Comment: If you replace `onclick` by `onfocus`, this will work by simply hit `<tab>` key, in chrome but not in firefox... May be a security issue!?

Answer (score 1):

With my latest version of Chrome - I only needed the following. Everytime I closed the app, it remembered my window size and position.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --chrome-frame --app=https://mightytext.net/web8/?exp=1
```

This worked for me in Version 48.0.2564.48 beta-m (64-bit)
and Version 48.0.2564.48 beta-m (64-bit)

Comment: The problem is that it requires manually adjusting the position and size first; they cannot be incorporated into the launching command.com

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:\Users\hello\gtemp\123" --window-size=100,1000 --window-position=3000,0 "https://www.openchromeonadifferentwindow.com"
```

1. Need `user-data-dir`.

> In order to run multiple separate Chrome browser processes, each of
> them needs its own profile. You can specify
> --user-data-dir="path/to/profile/#" (change # to a different number or use an entirely different path) when you run each browser instance.
> Note - the path does not have to exist, it only has to be legal (and
> Chrome should have permissions to create it in case it does not
> exist). Chrome will create profile paths that do not exist yet

.. Found it on this [link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-discuss/c/oE-KOCMMtrg) helpful.

2. The `window-position=3000,0` helps to move the window position to another monitor
3. Need to change the `user-data-dir` `#` to a different number if you want to open another instances with different settings