# Chrome --app equivalent in Firefox\IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have a web application which the customer requested that the browser window size will be changed when clicking on different buttons.

I found in that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436855/launch-google-chrome-from-the-command-line-with-specific-window-coordinates) that running the **"chrome.exe"** process with **"--app"** is very useful since the following javascript code will work even though it is not a child window:

```
window.moveTo(580,240);
window.resizeTo(800,600);
```

Is there any equivalent in Firefox and IE for this "--app" mode ?
Thanks !

Comment: You might want to check out the firefox [command line options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options). Another [relevant SuperUser Post](http://superuser.com/questions/55915/launching-firefox-into-chromeless-mode-from-command-prompt) that might come in handy.

Comment: Checked it already and did not find anything useful. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question. however it must be done through child window.
At first i tried to do the following:

```
var win = window.open(url);
win.resizeTo(800, 600);
```

That worked only when the parent window was alive. when i closed the parent, it did not work.
However the following function works even though you close the parent window:

```
window.resizeTo(800,600);
```

it works for all IE, Firefox and Chrome.
thanks !