# Open HTML in chrome from command line using app flag

Tags: bash, google-chrome

[(Before downvote im aware how to do this using code thats inline to this command but not how to do it using a file that uses the `--app="data:text/html,<sometags></sometags>`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962811/7159163)

How would I open a local html (mar.html) file using this command
`C:\'Program Files (x86)'\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Default" --app=`

Specifically, the issue is my lack of familiarity with the --app flag

I tried

`C:\'Program Files (x86)'\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Default" --app="mar.html"`

`C:\'Program Files (x86)'\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Default" --app="file:///mar.html"`

Both don't work.

Giving me the error

`Your file was not found
It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436855/launch-google-chrome-from-the-command-line-with-specific-window-coordinates, this can help you.

Comment: I tried that but no help.

Comment: @AndersonScoutodaSilva it doesn't mention at all how to open it using a **local** html file but only with URLs

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. The file descriptor path must be absolute and encoded.
Encoding the path correctly with cli tools like "urlencode"(gridsite-clients) did not work for me.

If you have NodeJS installed and would use a linux machine, you could use this command.

```
chromium --app=`node -e "console.log('file://'+encodeURI(process.argv[1]))" "$(realpath "/path/of/your/file.html")"`
```

This works also fine with relative paths.
For windows you have to rewrite this yourself.