# Launching Chrome with .bat file with specific scroll-down

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, scroll

This is a follow-up question to [Launching 2 Google Chrome windows in different positions](https://superuser.com/questions/888794/launching-2-google-chrome-windows-in-different-positions) and [Launch Google Chrome from the command line with specific window coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436855/launch-google-chrome-from-the-command-line-with-specific-window-coordinates/19789383).

Apart from what has already been said in those 2 posts, I am wondering if there is a command I can add to a batch file which allows me to **open a new Chrome window scrolled down to a specific position, or by a specific "amount"**.

I have checked [this page](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/) and [this page](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension) but have not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use sendkeys after opening chrome to open the console, focus on the console, and input some javascript to scroll 100px down.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

rem Start the other program in the same Window
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.8
timeout /t 2
%SendKeys% "^(+({J}))"
timeout /t 2
%SendKeys% "^(`)"
%SendKeys% "window.scrollBy{(}0, 100{)};~"


goto :EOF


@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```