# Blender Python Open Browser With Specific Size And In The Center Of The Screen

Tags: python, blender

I'm writing a blender python plugin which has an integrated connection to an online market, when the user buys a product (3d model) a window needs to open up to make the transaction through PayPal. The code I'm using works ok for that:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new("http://www.paypal.com/buyProductURL")
```

However the window does not open up in the center of the screen and I also cannot find out how to define the size of the browser window that is being opened.

How can I move the browser window to the center and how can I define its size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you want:

```
import webbrowser

browser = ' '.join([
    "chrome",
    "--chrome-frame",
    "--window-size=800,600",
    "--window-position=240,80",
    "--app=%s &",
])

webbrowser.get(browser).open('http://www.paypal.com/buyProductURL')
```

The `%s` parameter is the url used by the module. It's required to call the browser as a command with arguments.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436855/launch-google-chrome-from-the-command-line-with-specific-window-coordinates) are some answers on how to call chrome in the command line.

If you require portability with the same behavior across all browsers it seems to be unattainable to me. I don't think you have an alternative here unless you ship the browser with your code or write more code for browser alternatives like chrome, `firefox` and `opera`. I wrote a code where it would work as a popup-like on chrome and chromium and as a tab open on other browsers:

```
import webbrowser

try_browsers = {
    "chrome": [
        "chrome",
        "--chrome-frame",
        "--window-size=800,600",
        "--window-position=240,80",
        "--app=%s &",
    ],
}
try_browsers['chromium'] = try_browsers['chrome'][:]
try_browsers['chromium'][0] = 'chromium'
URL = 'http://www.paypal.com/buyProductURL'

for browser in try_browsers.values():
    if webbrowser.get(' '.join(browser)).open(URL):
        break
else:
    webbrowser.open(URL)
```